# Deleterow() within a For loop not deleting the right rows on GSheets

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Cant find out why this not deleting the right rows:
I've ried all possible combinations (in my head).

```
function deleteItem() { 
  var sourceSheet = 'ArquivoItens';
  var destinationSheet = 'EditarItem';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var source = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
  var LastRowSource = source.getLastRow();
  var LastColumnSource = source.getLastColumn();
  var values = source.getRange(2,1,LastRowSource,LastColumnSource).getValues();
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);
  var productCode = csh.getRange("W5").getValue();
  var productVersao = csh.getRange("AC4").getValue();

  for (var i = (values.length)-1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (values[i][0] == productCode && values[i][2] == productVersao) {
      Logger.log(values[i]);
      source.deleteRow(i);
      }
    }
}
```

Please let me knwo where the flaw is. Apreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function deleteItem() { 
  var sourceSheet = 'ArquivoItens';
  var destinationSheet = 'EditarItem';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var source = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
  var LastRowSource = source.getLastRow();
  var LastColumnSource = source.getLastColumn();
  //LastRowSource-startrow+1
  var values = source.getRange(2,1,LastRowSource-1,LastColumnSource).getValues();
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);
  var productCode = csh.getRange("W5").getValue();
  var productVersao = csh.getRange("AC4").getValue();

  for (var i = values.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (values[i][0] == productCode && values[i][2] == productVersao) {
      Logger.log(values[i]);
      source.deleteRow(i+2);//i+startrow which is two in this case
      }
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the rows to be deleted, if the productCode and productVersao criteria are met. See columns in bold:
[image]

Comment: This is deleting one row above instead. I've tried i+1, but it does the same.

Comment: I would need to see an image of your sheet

Comment: Just added a screenshot of them.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to reflect this, taking off () around values.length?
for (var i = values.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (values[i][0] == productCode && values[i][2] == productVersao) {
      source.deleteRow(i+2);
      }
    }
This is what worked for me. Could you explain me how?

Comment: I always take a look at the startRow for data.  Generally the row that your wanting to delete is easy to figure out by determining where the startRow of data is.  If you take the entire dataRange() then the starting row is 1 and if i=0 and starting row is 1 then the row your currently wanting to delete has to be i+1.  But generally it's almost always i+starting row number.   Keep in mind arrays starting indexing from zero and rows start from one. But if the first range of your row is 2 then when i=0 the row has to be 2 so hence i+2.

Comment: By the way you don't have to go backwards with your incrementing if you use a counter to keep a record of all of the rows you're deleting.  I almost alway like interacting in the positive direction like you always have to do with array methods.  In that case you can generally use the formula for deleting rows as sheet.deleteRow(i+sr-d++) where i is the index (ie the second parameter in  a forEach() and sr is starting row and d is the number of lines deleted thus far and the ++ if it's the last reference in the loop.

Comment: I'll have to sleep on it to be able to assimilate. Will revisit this explanation as I'm moving on here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`deleteRow` requires `row` number, while `i` is the index of the array. Array indexes start at  0, while row indexes start at 1.

```
source.deleteRow(i+1);
```